# Angular 6 - Passing a value from outlets to Component

Tags: angular, router-outlet

I need to pass a value to the outlet route.

This is my html template:

```
<li class="list-group-item *ngFor="let item of items">
    <ul class="list-inline">
        <li class="list-inline-item">
            <a [routerLink]="['/dashboard/', {outlets: {'mainOutlet':'viewdetail/'}}]"><span> {{item.doc}} - {{item.customer}}</span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

And I need to pass the value of item.id, I have tried different ways and I do not get it, it would be something like that, but I do not get the value of item.id, I disregard the syntax of how could put it correctly.

```
<a [routerLink]="['/dashboard/', {outlets: {'mainOutlet':'viewdetail/item.id'}}]"><span> {{item.customer}}</span></a>
```

Thanks for the help,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are setting 'item.id' as a string instead of the value

```
<a [routerLink]="['/dashboard/', {outlets: {'mainOutlet':'viewdetail/' +item.id}}]"><span> {{item.customer}}</span></a>
```

Comment: I also tried the +, and it did not work because I was not passing a correct data type, now everything works ok, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use something like this -

```
[routerLink]="['/dashboard', {outlets: { mainOutlet: ['viewdetail', item.id]} } ]"
```

Or

```
'mainOutlet':'viewdetail/' + item.id
```

Error is - you are treating your variable as string.

Comment: Or in your original syntax, replace `'mainOutlet':'viewdetail/item.id'` with `'mainOutlet':'viewdetail/' + item.id`